# public shows redundant visibility modifier in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, public, access-modifiers

I got a warning message on the public to indicate that its a redundant visibility modifier. Actually I call the function in different classes. Written kotlin.

```
public fun makeCurrentFragmentAnimLtRl(fragment: Fragment) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
                setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_left,
                    0, 0)
                replace(R.id.cl_wrapper, fragment)
                commit()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Methods are public by default in Kotlin. Even if u don't mention. public it will behave the same. Hence the message from the IDE

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin the [default visibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html), used if there is no explicit modifier, is `public`. You receive the warning from IDE "Redundant visibility modifier" because you can omit it.

Just write `fun makeCurrentFragmentAnimLtRl(fragment: Fragment) {...}` and the method will be **public** by default.